# Is it possible to group values in a map in an aggregate function with MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

My dataset is as follows:

```
{
    _id: "joe",
    email: "joe@joe.com",
    attributes: [ "eyes" : "blue", "height" : "6'0" ]
}
```

Is it possible to perform an aggregate by grouping particular values in the attributes map?

I.E

```
{ 
    $group : { 
        _id: { eyes: "$eyes" }, 
        number: { $sum: 1 } 
    } 
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it as follows :

```
db.myObject.aggregate(
  {$unwind : "$attributes"}, 
  {$group : {_id : {eyes : "$attributes.eyes"}, number : {$sum:1}}}
);
```